# How to fetch JSON data from external API with spring-batch and JsonItemReaderBuilder

Tags: spring-batch

I followed the [Spring Batch docs](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/) that works and is enough simple and banal, but still can't figure out how to apply the same technics for fetching JSON data from an external API. As far as I understand, I have to use `JsonItemReaderBuilder` and define the `reader` method to return an instance of `JsonItemReader` as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public JsonItemReader<Person> reader() {
        return new JsonItemReaderBuilder<Person>()
                .name("personItemReader")
                .build();
    }
```

The problem I'm stuck with is how to replace `.resource(new ClassPathResource("sample-data.csv"))` line in the above example which just reads a CSV file ? I think I have to pass in JSON data as `InputStream` instance or smth like that ? What kind of resource should I pass in ? Thank you.

Comment: I created an API at Heroku to be able to fetch some data (see URL in `BatchConfiguration.java` class). The part regarding PhraseApp request is commented out. I can fetch `posts` data from Heroku app, but getting `401` code when hitting the PhraseApp end-point. The reason comes from `this.resource.exists()` check in `JsonItemReader` Spring class (see my last comment).

Answer (score 5):

The `JsonItemReader` works with any `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` implementation. So in your case, you can use a `org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource`. Here is a quick example:

```
@Bean
public JsonItemReader<Person> reader() throws Exception {
    URL resource = new URL("http/url/to/file/persons.json");
    return new JsonItemReaderBuilder<Person>()
            .name("personItemReader")
            .resource(new UrlResource(resource))
            .jsonObjectReader(new JacksonJsonObjectReader<>(Person.class))
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @mahmoud-beh-hassine!  As far as I could see, I can pass `https://example.com/v2/some-end-point` to `URL` constructor, right? Will the above reader parse and map automatically to `Person` object? Do I need any other options to pass in to `JsonItemReaderBuilder` builder? How is it possible to set `Header` values (like `Authorization` for ex.)?

Comment: Should I get the connection as follows:`HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();` to be able to set the request headers: `con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");` or `con.setRequestProperty("Authorization Bearer", "some-tokenvalue -comes-here")`?

Comment: Yes, the reader would read the content of the `Resource` as if it was local. In regards to adding http headers, you can try to set them as you showed before passing the url to the `UrlResource` (good point BTW!).

Comment: OK, becomes clearer. One thing left to mention - should we close the connection in the end: `con.disconnect();`? (in `JobCompletionNotificationListener`, for example).

Comment: It does not work either, I get `Error creating bean with name 'reader' defined in class path resource [hello/BatchConfiguration.class]`, `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A json object reader is required.` I created a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/belgoros/14875f891097482acef888d403b7b3e7) to give an idea.

Comment: You need a json object reader, I edited the answer with an example. In regards to the connection, you can close it with a listener or use try-with-resources (which is simpler in my opinion).

Comment: After updating stil failed with: `org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader`, `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode)`, `org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Error while closing item reader`

Comment: The more complete [Gist](https://gist.github.com/belgoros/4ccdb2731223451c73c211de1746755f)

Comment: I added an example to your gist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195867/discussion-between-belgoros-and-mahmoud-ben-hassine).